# Accessing third-party login profile from a role in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm building an application in which I only allow users to log in using OAuth 2 via a third party service (e.g. Twitter, Facebook, etc).

I'm also defining a custom role using `Role.registerResolver` and ACLs to enable groups of users to gain permissions on objects to which they should have access.

In order to figure out if the user belongs to the group, I need to call the login provider's API to query for some data, and to do this, I need the user's 3rd party `AccessToken` that was provided during the log in.

Assuming the user is logged in and has a valid session, how can I get access to the `req.user` object from the `RoleResolver`? I can't seem to figure out how to do that from the `context` that is passed to the resolver.

Is there a recommended way to get this information?

Comment: Is it not on `context.req.user`?

Comment: It is not in this context..

Answer (score 0):

This is shortcut.

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  var Role = app.models.Role;
  Role.registerResolver('teamMember', function(role, context, cb) {

    var userId = context.accessToken.userId
  })
}
```